# How to get a spinner to display textview

Tags: android, android-event

I am trying to make a spinner that will display a different text view each time an item from the list has been selected. When I run my code, I am able to switch between the different items, but the text is not updating based on the selection. I have looked at a variety of similar questions but none of their solutions have done what I am looking for.

Here is my code from the main activity:

```
Spinner spinner;
TextView example;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    example = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.medication_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:
                    example.setText("Depression");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    example.setText(R.string.ssriexample);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    example.setText(R.string.snriexample);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    example.setText(R.string.tcaexample);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    example.setText(R.string.moiexample);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    example.setText(R.string.otherexample);
                    break;

            }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

}

Any tips would be apprieated as this is my first time coding in android studios and it's taking a little bit of time to get used to.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to populate your spinner with an XML file.  Then your string value is held there and can be accessed using the selected index.

Comment: have you added spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way your code is posted, it looks like your listeners are not attached to the spinner. Call `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new listener)` or `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)`

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!